# git error message: rebase_head does not exist

Tags: git

I just did a "git pull --rebase" and everything looks fine except the last few lines:

```
> 5 files changed, 62 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-) Current branch master is up to date. 
> Path/.git/REBASE_HEAD does not exist
> Path/.git/rebase-apply does not exist
```

Should I be concerned about this?
How can I restore REBASE_HEAD and rebase-apply?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restore them unless there was a conflict during the rebase:

- REBASE_HEAD is the current patch in an interactive rebase or when rebase is stopped because of conflict
- rebase-apply is the original branch (before being rebased)

If you haven't seen any conflict during the rebase phase of the git pull, you can ignore that message.